# Game Center IBAction Achievement

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, game-center

I've been  working with Game Center recently (achievements) and i only know how to do score based achievements. How can I do something like this?

```
-(IBAction) {

//Unlock Achievement 

}
```

I understand everything else about game center except for this. Thank You!

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  An `IBAction` just defines an action that is attached to an element on the interface.  Are you trying to create a button or other UI element that will unlock an achievement?

Comment: I would just like to use a button to unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to create an IBAction from a button:

Programmatically:

```
UIButton *theButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 240, 50, 20)];

[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(unlockAch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:theButton];
```

then create the method:

```
-(IBAction)unlockAch:(id)sender
{
    //Unlock code
}
```

Or you can do it using interface builder.  Create the button and hold down Ctrl, click on the button, and drag into the .h file.  You will get a popup that allows you to create an action and give it a name:

[image]

Then interface builder will drop it into your .h and .m files and it will be connected and ready to go!

[image]

Comment: Thats not the problem, I know how to set up the IBAction but i don't know the code for unlocking the achievement.

Comment: From your description is sounded like you've been working with achievements already and now you are trying to figure out how to make an IBAction.  Just put a call inside your IBAction that does the method that unlocks your achievement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of I suggest that you use a singleton helper class (let's call it GCAssistant) to handle game-center specific actions. Like explained in [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12) tutorial.

In the class header, define the achievement ID's so that it's easier to submit achievements when you're coding; like below:

```
#define kAchievementChainer @"1C"
#define kAchievementBoardClear @"1A"
#define kAchievement7Games @"1B"
#define kAchievement77Games @"1D"
#define kAchievementBreakAll @"1E"
#define kAchievementMultiplayer @"1F"
```

In the helper class, this is the method I use to submit achievements:

```
-(void) reportAchievementWithID:(NSString*) AchievementID {

[GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error) {

    if(error) NSLog(@"error");

    for (GKAchievement *ach in achievements) {
        if([ach.identifier isEqualToString:AchievementID]) { //already submitted
            NSLog(@"Already submitted");
            return ;
        }
    }

    GKAchievement *achievementToSend = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:AchievementID];
    achievementToSend.percentComplete = 100;
    achievementToSend.showsCompletionBanner = YES;
    [achievementToSend reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:NULL];

}];

}
```

This method checks if an achievement was submitted before; and submits it if it wasn't. So anywhere in your project you can do (as long as the class GCAssistant is imported):

```
[[GCAssistant sharedInstance] reportAchievementWithID:kAchievementChainer];
```

It is not in the documentation and I also didn't know about this until I watched WWDC 2012 videos but iOS 5 takes care of resubmitting scores/achievements if there is an error. So you don't have to worry about manually storing unsent submissions etc for iOS 5 and above.

For your question, as you may be guessing by now, all you have to do is to call:

```
[[GCAssistant sharedInstance] reportAchievementWithID:kYourAchievementID];
```

in your `IBAction` method. Good luck and let me know if you have any problems.